# How can I make BitmapFactory.decodeStream faster?

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I let users upload a own image from gallery. Those images can be pretty big and because of that, my program runs sometimes very slow when I load it to an ImageView.

This is where I load the Bitmap from memory:

```
public Bitmap load() {
    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(createFile());
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And here I set it to the ImageView:

```
private void setBackground(){
    final Bitmap bitmap = imageSaver.load();

    if(bitmap != null){
        imageViewBackground.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }
}
```

So my question is; how can I make this code faster so that all picture sizes will load without making my program slow.

Thanks for help!

Comment: The #1 thing to do is stop doing disk I/O on the main application thread. Use an image-loading library, such as Picasso, that can do the image-loading asynchronously.

Comment: How about resizing the images when they are uploaded by your users?

Comment: `let users upload a own image from gallery. `. To a server somewhere i would think.

Comment: `when I load it to an ImageView.`. Yes load. Not upload.

Comment: If the image is pretty big then BitmapFactory will return null. So nothing loads.

Comment: `createFile()`. What does that function do? You are not showing us what you are doing. So how can we comment?

Comment: `where I load the Bitmap from memory:`. From memory? How? You are not showing that.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, read data as byte

```
fun readBytesFromUri(uri: Uri, context: Context): ByteArray? {
        val inputStream = context.contentResolver?.openInputStream(uri)
        val bytes = inputStream?.readBytes()
        inputStream?.close()
        return bytes
    }
```

Then convert byte data to bitmap

```
fun byteArrayToBitmap(byteArray: ByteArray?): Bitmap? {
        return byteArray?.size?.let { BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, it) }
    }
```